# Android - How to check all command buttons are erased ( or invisible)

Tags: android, button

Once User clicked the button, i want the button to be Invisible)  Like below.

Command button displaying the below values.

```
         8     4     3    2              ( If user press  4 then that it should not be 
                                               displayed )

         8           3    2               ( But the button position is displayed ).
```

In this i need to check how all the buttons are invisible now.  Please see my current code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lm);

        // Create a LinearLayout for each row inside the outer LinearLayout.
        LinearLayout firstRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        firstRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        // Create a String array of items you want to add to the inner LinearLayout.
        String[] itemsToAddToFirstRow = { "4", "2", "8", "3"};
        createButtonsDynamically(firstRow, itemsToAddToFirstRow);

        String[] itemsToAddToSecondRow = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
        LinearLayout secondRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        secondRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        createButtonsDynamically(secondRow, itemsToAddToSecondRow);
    }

    private void createButtonsDynamically(LinearLayout layoutToAddButtonsTo, String[] itemsToAdd) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToAdd.length; i++) {
            final Button buttonToAdd = new Button(this);
            buttonToAdd.setText(itemsToAdd[i]);
            buttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Strvalue = (String) buttonToAdd.getText();
                        buttonToAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            layoutToAddButtonsTo.addView(buttonToAdd);
        }

        // In the end add all buttons inside the inner LinearLayout to the outer LinearLayout.
        lm.addView(layoutToAddButtonsTo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this may help you...

```
private void checkButtonsVisibility(LinearLayout layout) {
    for (int i = 0, N = layout.getChildCount(); i < N; i++) {
        Button button = (Button) layout.getChildAt(i);
        int visibility = button.getVisibility();
        if(visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            // button is visble. do something...
        } else if(visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
            // button is invisible. do something
        } else {
            // button is gone
        }
    }
}
```